# UI for custom merge

Tags: visualforce, html, merge

I'm working on a custom object merge feature and am having difficulty replicating the standard SF merge UI. I'm hoping to use `<apex:selectRadio>` to display field values on a row, with the columns representing the different records. The radio option value (value attribute in `<input type="radio">`) would contain the record Id and the option label the field value. That way, when merging, I can just pull the `<apex:selectRadio>` value and know which record to copy the field data from.

I cannot get `<apex:selectRadio>` to display the field values correctly within a row because it outputs a `<fieldset>` containing a `<table>` .

Anyone done this using `<apex:selectRadio>`? Any other approaches/suggestions welcome.

For those not familiar with SF's standard merge UI, here it is:

[image]

Here's what I've tried so far:

**VF**

```
<apex:page standardController="Widget__c" extensions="WidgetMergeExt" showHeader="true" sidebar="true" recordSetVar="widgets">

  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock>
      <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!fields}" var="field">
        <apex:column>
          <apex:selectRadio value="{!field.radioValue}">
            <apex:selectOptions value="{!field.options}"/>
          </apex:selectRadio>
        </apex:column>
      </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Apex**

```
public with sharing class WidgetMergeExt {

    private ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon;
    public List<String> fieldNames {get; set;}
    public List<Field> fields {get; set;}

    public WidgetMergeExt(ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon) {
        this.setCon = setCon;
        fieldNames = new List<String> {'Name','CreatedDate','LastModifiedDate'};
        fields = new List<Field>();
        List<Widget__c> widgetsToMerge = [ SELECT Name,CreatedDate,LastModifiedDate FROM Widget__c WHERE Id IN :setCon.getSelected() ];
        for (String fieldName : fieldNames) {
            List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();
            for (Widget__c widget : widgetsToMerge) {
                String value = String.valueOf(widget.Id);
                String label = String.valueOf(widget.get(fieldName));
                options.add(new SelectOption(value, label));
            }
            fields.add(new Field(options));
        }
    }

    class Field {
        public List<SelectOption> options {get; set;}
        public String radioValue {get; set;}
        public Field(List<SelectOption> options) {
            this.options = options;
            this.radioValue = '';
        }
    }
}
```

Because `<apex:selectRadio>` outputs a table, the result is a single-column table with the column containing the selectRadio-generated table with a  for each option like so:

(example row)

```
  <tr class="dataRow even  first" onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onblur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onfocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}">
    <td class=" dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id4" colspan="1">
      <fieldset style="border: none;">
        <table role="presentation">
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5" id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5:0" value="a0KM0000009OusKMAS">
                <label for="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5:0">Test Record 1</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5" id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5:1" value="a0KM0000009OusLMAS">
                <label for="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5:1">Test Record 2</label>
              </td>
              <td>
                <input type="radio" name="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5" id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5:2" value="a0KM0000009OusMMAS">
                <label for="j_id0:j_id1:j_id2:j_id3:0:j_id5:2">Test Record 3</label>
              </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </fieldset>
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Salesforce Foundation's Nonprofit Starter Pack has a custom merge functionality with a "paint your own record" type UI. The code is open source. Here is a good overview of the functionality:

http://salesforcefoundation.screenstepslive.com/s/npsp/m/contacts/l/20012-merging-contacts

And here is a link to the code:

Helper Class: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/src/classes/CON_ContactMerge.cls

Controller: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/src/classes/CON_ContactMerge_CTRL.cls

Test: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/src/classes/CON_ContactMerge_TEST.cls

VF Page: https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/dev/src/pages/CON_ContactMerge.page

Comment: The helper class link appears to be incorrect. Please revise when you get a chance.

Comment: I've edited my original post to fix the link

Comment: I guess this isn't open source anymore? The links return an error.

Comment: Code's at https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/
* [Helper Class](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/master/src/classes/CON_ContactMerge.cls)
* [Controller](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/master/src/classes/CON_ContactMerge_CTRL.cls)
* [Test](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/master/src/classes/CON_ContactMerge_TEST.cls)
* [VF Page](https://github.com/SalesforceFoundation/Cumulus/blob/master/src/pages/CON_ContactMerge.page)

Comment: @greenstork the directory structure in the repo has changed. Could you update your links accordingly?

Comment: @AndyHitchings it still is, but the directory structure in the repo has changed since this answer